# Infragistics webdropdown SelectedItemIndex issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, infragistics

i want to know how can i reset Infragistics webdropdown SelectedItemIndex to -1 and its value to initial value when a user delete an item from Infragistics webdropdown. i was trying it with client method OnBlur. I want to know, if there is any better approach on this. I added my code below. Could  anybody help me out..

```
function OnDropdownBlur(sender, args) {
            if (sender.get_currentValue() === "") {
        sender.set_currentValue("", true);
        sender.set_selectedItemIndex(-1);
    }
    else {
        sender.set_selectedItemIndex(sender.get_selectedItemIndex());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple. You can set the webdropdown by an index as below.

```
sender.selectItemByIndex(-1)
```

Note: If you want to have the text "Select" after resetting, then you should use

```
sender.set_currentValue('Select')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are doing this for when the user deletes the text from the text box portion of the drop down.  If so then you should be able to remove the else condition since setting the selectedItemIndex to its current value isn't actually doing anything.

Note that the initial value of the drop down by default is the first item in the drop down rather than an empty string unless you have your first item have an empty string in the TextField.  If you wished to do this and still have the selected index be -1 like it is initially, you could use the following to set the value of the drop down:

```
sender.set_currentValue(sender.get_items().getItem(0).get_text(), true);
```